# For loop repeating endlessly in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

From everything I have looked at I cannot seem to find any problem with my code.

```
int main()
{   
double honorpoints,totalhp = 0,totalcredits = 0;
int crpassed=0,clpassed = 0, count;
float GPA,credits;
char classx,grade;
printf("How many classes did you take in the semester: ");
scanf("%d", &count);
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{ 
    printf("Enter a Class: \n");
    scanf("%s", &classx);
    printf("Enter the number of credits: ");
    scanf("%f",&credits);
    totalcredits = totalcredits + credits;
    printf("Enter your grade: ");
    scanf("%s",&grade);
    if (grade == 'A')
    {
       honorpoints = credits * 4;
       crpassed = crpassed + credits;
       clpassed = clpassed + 1;
    }
    else if (grade == 'B')
    {
       honorpoints = 3 * credits;
       crpassed = crpassed + credits;
       clpassed = clpassed + 1;
    }
    else if (grade == 'C')
    {
       honorpoints = 2 * credits;
       crpassed = crpassed + credits;
       clpassed = clpassed + 1;
    }
    else if (grade == 'D')
    {
       honorpoints = 1 * credits;
       crpassed = crpassed + credits;
       clpassed = clpassed + 1;
    }
    else
       honorpoints=0;
    totalhp = totalhp + honorpoints;
}
```

When asking for classes it just continues over and over again. it does run through everything in the loop but it does not stop when 'count' is reached it just continuously asks for classes and grades. I am relatively new to working with C so forgive me if this is an obvious syntax error or something but even while looking through other threads I cannot find a problem with mine.

Comment: Because `grade` is a char, read it with `%c`, not `%s`.

Comment: in addition to the errors other are describing, you're not checking the result of any `scanf` calls ; you don't know whether they successfully read the input you expect.  You should validate the result of `scanf`

Comment: If you follow jarmod's suggestions and try to read a `char` with `%c`, make sure the format you use is actually `" %c"` (note the extra space).

Comment: (Why do you need the extra space? Because `scanf` is a tarpit of little mysteries like that.)

Comment: changing it to %c, both with an without the space did not change anything, I am still getting too many iterations of the loop.

Comment: Well, `%c` is never going to work for reading a course name.  I think you want to read the course name as a *string*, meaning you need to keep the `%s`, change `char classx` to something like `char classx[50]`, and drop the `&` when you call `scanf` for it, as Tom Karzes was hinting.

Comment: Your main problem here is `scanf`.  Despite its seeming simplicity, and despite the fact that everyone uses it (or, *tries* to use it) in programs like these, it is not your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the `scanf` calls are corrupting memory, resulting in undefined behavior.  `classx` and `grade` are both single characters:

```
char classx,grade;
```

So the following `scanf` calls won't work properly:

```
scanf("%s", &classx);
scanf("%s", &grade);
```

If these values are meant to be single characters, you can use `%c` as the `scanf` format.  Otherwise, if you want to read strings, then you need to declare them as arrays, and pass them without taking their address.  In that case, don't forget to add a character for the terminating null character.

In either case, you may want to change the format strings so that they consume whitespace (you can prefix the format string with a space to achieve that).

Comment: Does "without taking their address" refer to taking away the & at the beginning? Just want to clarify my understanding.

Comment: @SierraWalker Yes.  `%s` is an exception.  Normally you always need `&` on the variables you fill with `scanf`, but not when you're filling an array with `%s`.